# No Visible @interface for UIAlertView Error

Tags: objective-c

Hi I am currently trying out the iOS 6 programming book by David mark et.al and I'm working on the Autorotation and Autosizing section.

I would be grateful if any1 could help me fix this annoying error that keeps popping up:

The following code is in the .m file:

```
#import "BIDViewController.h"

#define degreesToradians(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)

@interface BIDViewController ()

@end

@implementation BIDViewController

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        self.view = self.portrait;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform =
        CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToradians(0));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,460.0);
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        self.view = self.landscape;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform =
        CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToradians(-90));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,480.0,300.0);
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation ==
        UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            self.view = self.landscape;
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            self.view.transform =
            CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToradians(90));
            self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,480.0,300.0);
        }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *message = nil;

    if ([self.foos containsObject:sender])
        message = @"Foo Button Pressed";
    else
        message = @"Bar Button Pressed";

    **UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initwithtitle:message**
                                                    message:nil
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
@end
```

the error that pops up is "no visible @interface for 'UIAlertView'...

I have tried locating typos regarding "Titles" but the error is still there..and this is for iOS!

ANY HELP ?

Thanks

Comment: Check the casing of iniWithTitle

Comment: please see the Related section in right-bottom side of your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 1):

`initwithtitle:`... should be `initWithTitle:`... Please thoroughly check your work before posting a question like this however. Also posting the full error would be more helpful.